# Is a “seam” only for sewn fabric?

Tags: idioms, terminology

> Similarly, if you drop your phone in the hotel loo and tell the reception staff "It's rooted," they might start looking for **vegetation sprouting from the seams**. ([The Age](http://www.theage.com.au/travel/its-rooted-aussie-terms-that-foreigners-just-wont-get-20140521-38nlc.html))

Vegetation sprouts from the seams? How on earth it comes out of “[a folded back and stitched piece of fabric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seam).” Is it an idiom denoting a kind of pun: ‘vegetation can sprout from the **seeds**, but how goodness from the **seams**’? So this expression might be saying they are in a state of confusing? What does it mean?

Comment: Wow, that wikidictionary entry is really terrible.  A seam, in sewing terminology, is where one piece of fabric is affixed to another piece of fabric by means of stitching; they can be the same piece of fabric if one folds it over, but "folding back" is never required for something to be a seam.  Furthermore, I'm of the impression that stitching in a single piece of fabric which doesn't join two pieces (stitches which are ornamental, e.g.) -- as would fit their definition -- is not considered a seam, but I would have to check that with an actual embroiderer.

Comment: @Codeswitcher According to my mother (former seamstress) decorative stitching is NOT a seam. It is just stitching. P.S. Embroidery calls them stitches too and seams rarely play a part in embroidery (except for nicely cleaning up the edges of the piece of embroidery or when affixing it onto another piece of cloth.)

Comment: "A folded back and stitched piece [singular] of fabric" would be a fair definition of a *hem* or a *selvage* (self-edge). A *seam* is always a join.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing came to my mind was those small trees that grow from those cracks in the walls or pavement. Why? Because I got some of them myself!

[image]
<sub>NOTE: If I don't pull them off, they will grow really fast. So, yes, they rooted indeed!</sub>

---

I believe that **seams** can be used so in your sentence because besides those stitches, it can mean:

> A line where the edges of two pieces of wood, wallpaper, or another material touch each other
>   <sub>Source: [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seam?q=seam)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a pun, but a perfectly correct idiomatic use of the word "seam" to mean any kind of straight line where two materials are joined. This appears as the last meaning in the Wikitionary entry:

> A line of junction; a joint.

For example, a *welding seam*:

[image]